# Transforming functions for OLS regression help

Tags: regression, data-transformation, least-squares, econometrics

I was wondering if you would be able to help me with an econometric problem regarding OLS regression. Part of my research is transforming functions in order to be used in stata example: Q = e^(B0 +B1(P) therefore it would just be ln(Q) = B0 + B1P on Stata.

I am trying to estimate the parameters of the following demand curve Q = B0P^B1, 
and transform the function/data in such a way as to permit estimation by
OLS, and report the results.

Q = BOP^B1 
Thanks

Comment: What are the variables, what are the parameters, and what specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

For a function of Q=B0P^B1 the resulting transformation for and OLS regression would be in the form ln(Q) = B0 + B1ln(P) therefore double log (log - log) formation.

SN:  the log of a product is the sum of the logs.